# Get random numbers in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following function in F#:

```
let randomCh () = 
        let random = Random()
        alph.Chars (random.Next (alph.Length - 1));
```

This function returns same value each time. I had same problem in C#, and solution very simple: create just one Random object like this:

```
    var rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(10));
```

How can I reach same behaviour in F#: get each time random value?

Comment: Have you tried creating just one `Random` object?

Comment: Assuming that `alph` is a `string`, the `randomCh` function most definitely doesn't return the same value each time. Please provide a self-contained repro of your problem.

Comment: @Mark Seemann , https://dotnetfiddle.net/OYV2ba

Comment: although, I'm not Andrey :)

Comment: Whenever `randomCh` is called you recreate the `Random` object using the default constructor. AFAIK this initializes the seed from the the current time. If you call this multiple times in a short time the same seed might be used giving you the same value over and over again. @krontogiannis answer don't have this problem

Comment: You should accept the answer if your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 7):

Well your C# code doesn't define a function whereas your F# does; you could have the same problem in C#. You should either refactor your `random` definition out of the `randomCh` function, or bind `randomCh` to a function after initializing `random`:

```
let alph = "abcdefg"

let randomCh = 
    let random = Random()
    fun () -> alph.Chars (random.Next (alph.Length - 1))

printfn "%O" <| randomCh()
printfn "%O" <| randomCh()
```

Answer (score 5):

Just like in C#, you should pull the creation of the random outside of your function.  This will prevent you from creating a new `Random` generator each call.  By default, `Random` uses the current system clock to seed itself - if you call a function, with the random instance inside of it, quickly in succession, you can seed the random with the same time stamps, effectively giving you the same sequence.

By moving it outside of the function, you will reuse the same random instance, and avoid that:

```
let random = Random()

let randomCh () =         
    alph.Chars (random.Next (alph.Length - 1));

// Calling randomCh() repeatedly will now give different values each time
```