# F# System.Random in a Recursive function doing funny stuff

Tags: list, recursion, random, f#

I have this funktion that chooses 4 randoms colors and makes a list of it. Atleast i want it too.:

```
let theList = [Red;Green;Yellow;Purple;White;Black]
let rec a x =
  let rnd = System.Random()
  match x with 
  |0 -> []
  |_ -> (List.item(rnd.Next(6)) theList)::(a (x-1))
```

The problem is though it picks a random color every time i run the funktion then it always picks the same color for the entire list. [Red;Red;Red;Red] or [Green;Green;Green;Green] etc.

It is a mystery to me how it can arrive at the same color everytime it makes the recursive call.

If i use the random method in a for loop then no problem.

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: Move your `System.Random()` call out of the function and it will work. I'll write a longer answer explaining why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get random numbers in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898225/get-random-numbers-in-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `System.Random()` call out of the function and it will work. What you're doing is:

```
let rec a x =
    let rnd = System.Random()
    // ... Some code that calls rnd.Next() once, then recurses
```

Every time you recurse, you're creating a new `System.Random` instance and assigning it to `rnd`. That means that you're using the default constructor of `System.Random`, and [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) warns that:

> ... different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers.

What you really want is to create a single `Random` instance, then use its `.Next()` method repeatedly. One way would be to move the `System.Random()` constructor call outside of the function:

```
let theList = [Red;Green;Yellow;Purple;White;Black]
let rnd = System.Random()
let rec a x =    
    match x with 
    |0 -> []
    |_ -> (List.item(rnd.Next(6)) theList)::(a (x-1))
```

Another way, if you don't want to expose the `rnd` name to outside code, would be to turn `a` into an "inner" function that's nested inside an outer function (in the following example, `doit` is the outer function):

```
let theList = [Red;Green;Yellow;Purple;White;Black]
let doit x =
    let rnd = System.Random()
    let rec a x =
        match x with 
        |0 -> []
        |_ -> (List.item(rnd.Next(6)) theList)::(a (x-1))
    a x
```

Both of these should produce the truly random (well, pseudo-random) results that you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you so much!